# Can't delete User due to SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey) error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, sqlite3-ruby

I'm a beginner working on a Ruby on Rails application where I want to ensure that deleting a user also deletes their associated messages, participants, and rooms. I have set up associations, but I am facing issues with the deletion process. It's a business directory that has a chat feature and after building it out (following some tutorial) I'm discovering I can't delete the User

I have the following models:
**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

    # definine the relationships
    has_many :services, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :messages,  dependent: :destroy
    has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy                   # Add this line
    has_many :rooms, through: :participants, dependent: :destroy  # added to test

    # used to display all users except the current user
    #change to (somehow) only show users that have started a chat with them
    scope :all_except, ->(user) { where.not(id: user) }

    def self.with_messages
      joins(:messages).where.not(messages: { body: nil }).distinct
    end


    # broadcast that a new user has been added
    after_create_commit { broadcast_append_to "users" }


    # roles that say what kind of user they are
    enum role: { customer: 0, businessperson: 1, admin: 2 }

    #validates that the username is unique
    validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true

    #makes sure the user inputs a phone number in an appropriate format 0XXXXXXXXX
    validates :phone_number, format: { with: /\A0\d{9}\z/, message: 'must start with 0 and be 10 digits' }, allow_blank: true

    # UNCOMMENT after you've seeded user in the schema with :profile picture
    #mount_uploader :profile_picture, ProfilePictureUploader # to upload profile picture

    
    def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
      ["created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "firstname", "id", "lastname", "password_digest", "phone_number", "profession", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "role", "updated_at", "username"]
    end


    def average_rating
      services_with_reviews = services.includes(:reviews).where.not(reviews: { rating: nil })
      total_ratings = services_with_reviews.sum { |service| service.reviews.average(:rating).round(0) }
      
      if services_with_reviews.size.positive?
        total_ratings / services_with_reviews.size
      else
        0 # or any default value you prefer when there are no reviews available
      end
    end
    

    def total_num_ratings
      services_with_reviews = services.includes(:reviews).where.not(reviews: { rating: nil })
      services_with_reviews.size
    end


    def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions.to_h).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { value: login.downcase }]).first
      else
        find_by(conditions)
      end
    end
  

  end
```

**Participants**

```
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
end
```

**Room**

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
    scope :public_rooms, -> { where(is_private: false) }
    after_create_commit { broadcast_if_public } #only broadcasting a channel/room if it's public
    
    has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy
  
    # broadcast the adding of a room if its a public one
    def broadcast_if_public
      broadcast_append_to 'rooms' unless is_private
    end
  

    def self.create_private_room(users, room_name)
      single_room = Room.create(name: room_name, is_private: true)
      users.each do |user|
        Participant.create(user_id: user.id, room_id: single_room.id)
      end
      single_room
    end

    def participant?(room, user)
      room.participants.where(user: user).exists?
    end

  end
```

**Message**

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
  after_create_commit { broadcast_append_to room }
  before_create :confirm_participant

  def confirm_participant
    return unless room.is_private

    is_participant = Participant.where(user_id: user.id, room_id: room.id).first
    throw :abort unless is_participant
  end
end
```

**My Schema**

```
ctiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_11_17_214308) do
  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "namespace"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.integer "resource_id"
    t.string "author_type"
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author"
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource"
  end

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "room_id", null: false
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["room_id"], name: "index_messages_on_room_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_messages_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "participants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "room_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["room_id"], name: "index_participants_on_room_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_participants_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.boolean "is_private", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "profession"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "role", default: 0
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "firstname"
    t.string "lastname"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "messages", "rooms", on_delete: :cascade
  add_foreign_key "messages", "users", on_delete: :cascade
  add_foreign_key "participants", "rooms"
  add_foreign_key "participants", "users"
  add_foreign_key "services", "locations"
end
```

**The error message** plus something a commenter asked me to do I though i might as well add the results of his suggestion (unless i got it wrong somewhere)

```
irb(main):013:0> User.last.destroy
  User Load (21.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (1.6ms)  begin transaction
  Service Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE "services"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 8]]
  Review Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 8]]
  Favorite Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 8]]
  Message Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 8]]
  User Destroy (23.9ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 8]]
  TRANSACTION (1.6ms)  rollback transaction
C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.6.5-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step': SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey)
C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.6.5-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step': FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (SQLite3::ConstraintException)
irb(main):014:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF")
   (0.4ms)  PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF
=> []
irb(main):015:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_check")
   (1.9ms)  PRAGMA foreign_key_check
=> []
irb(main):016:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
   (0.1ms)  PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
=> []
irb(main):017:0>
```

Checking what's violating the contraint

```
irb(main):017:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF")
   (2.2ms)  PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF
=> []
irb(main):018:0> User.last.destroy
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  Service Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE "services"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 8]]
  Review Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 8]]
  Favorite Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 8]]
  Message Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 8]]
  User Destroy (2.6ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 8]]
  TRANSACTION (10.9ms)  commit transaction
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>
irb(main):019:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_check")
   (6.9ms)  PRAGMA foreign_key_check
=> [{"table"=>"participants", "rowid"=>13, "parent"=>"users", "fkid"=>1}]
irb(main):020:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
   (0.1ms)  PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
=> []
irb(main):021:0>
```

After adding `belongs_to :participant` to Message model and restarting the console

```
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform> rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.8)
irb(main):001:0> User.last.destroy
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Service Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE "services"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 7]]
  Review Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 36]]
  Image Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 36]]
  Favorite Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 36]]
  Service Destroy (1.1ms)  DELETE FROM "services" WHERE "services"."id" = ?  [["id", 36]]
  Review Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 7]]
  Favorite Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 7]]
  Participant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 7]]
  Participant Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."id" = ?  [["id", 3]]
  Room Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 22], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."room_id" = ?  [["room_id", 22]]
  Message Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 11]]
  Message Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 12]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 13]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 14]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 15]]
  Message Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 16]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 17]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 18]]
  Message Destroy (0.9ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 19]]
  Message Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 20]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 21]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 22]]
  Message Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 23]]
  Message Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 24]]
  Message Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 25]]
  Message Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 26]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 27]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 28]]
  Message Destroy (0.6ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 29]]
  Message Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 30]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 31]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 32]]
  Message Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 33]]
  Message Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 35]]
  Message Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 36]]
  Message Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 41]]
  Message Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ?  [["id", 42]]
  Participant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."room_id" = ?  [["room_id", 22]]
  Participant Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."id" = ?  [["id", 4]]
  TRANSACTION (2.5ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
irb(main):002:0>
```

**EDIT**
I've tried messing around with the relations, adding stuff and deleting stuff so much so that I'm worried I may have made things worse.

I've added the rest of the code for the models maybe you'll see something. And thank you for the comments so far even though I hadn't given you everything.

Also from what i understand the reason for the participant's class is to have something to check if a person was a participant of that room/conversation. Or to add them as a participant.

To be honest, now that I think about it using users instead of participants would have been better. I regret following that but I'm here now.

**EDIT 2**
Added the error Code

**EDIT 3**
Added @Alex's suggestion to see what was violating the constraint

**EDIT 4**
added`belongs_to :participant` to Message model and restarted the console. Tried User.last.destroy and got `false`

**EDIT 5**
Not sure if I messed something up so I'm reposting my models. Below that is an error that I'm getting. It worked but now it's not working so I think there's something I did.

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

    # definine the relationships
    has_many :services, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy                   # Add this line
    has_many :rooms, through: :participants                       # added to test # deleted "dependent: :destroy "

    # used to display all users except the current user
    #change to (somehow) only show users that have started a chat with them
    scope :all_except, ->(user) { where.not(id: user) }

    def self.with_messages
      joins(:messages).where.not(messages: { body: nil }).distinct
    end


    # broadcast that a new user has been added
    after_create_commit { broadcast_append_to "users" }


    # roles that say what kind of user they are
    enum role: { customer: 0, businessperson: 1, admin: 2 }

    #validates that the username is unique
    validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true

    #makes sure the user inputs a phone number in an appropriate format 0XXXXXXXXX
    validates :phone_number, format: { with: /\A0\d{9}\z/, message: 'must start with 0 and be 10 digits' }, allow_blank: true

    # UNCOMMENT after you've seeded user in the schema with :profile picture
    #mount_uploader :profile_picture, ProfilePictureUploader # to upload profile picture

    
    def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
      ["created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "firstname", "id", "lastname", "password_digest", "phone_number", "profession", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "role", "updated_at", "username"]
    end


    def average_rating
      services_with_reviews = services.includes(:reviews).where.not(reviews: { rating: nil })
      total_ratings = services_with_reviews.sum { |service| service.reviews.average(:rating).round(0) }
      
      if services_with_reviews.size.positive?
        total_ratings / services_with_reviews.size
      else
        0 # or any default value you prefer when there are no reviews available
      end
    end
    

    def total_num_ratings
      services_with_reviews = services.includes(:reviews).where.not(reviews: { rating: nil })
      services_with_reviews.size
    end


    def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions.to_h).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { value: login.downcase }]).first
      else
        find_by(conditions)
      end
    end
  

  end
```

**Messages**

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :participant
  
  after_create_commit { broadcast_append_to room }
  before_create :confirm_participant

  def confirm_participant
    return unless room.is_private

    is_participant = Participant.where(user_id: user.id, room_id: room.id).first
    throw :abort unless is_participant
  end
end
```

**Participants**

```
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room # dependent: :destroy removed recentely
end
```

**Review**

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :service, dependent: :destroy

    # only have one review UNCOMMENT LATER
    #validates :service_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id, message: "You have already reviewed this service" }
  end
```

The error

```
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform> rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.8)
irb(main):001:0>  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF")
   (0.1ms)  PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF
=> []
irb(main):002:0> User.last.destroy
  User Load (16.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Service Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE "services"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 6]]
  Review Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 1]]
  Review Destroy (10.4ms)  DELETE FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."id" = ?  [["id", 8]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Service Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE "services"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
  Review Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 38]]
  Image Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 38]]
  Favorite Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 38]]
  Service Destroy (1.4ms)  DELETE FROM "services" WHERE "services"."id" = ?  [["id", 38]]
  Review Load (11.1ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 39]]
  Image Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 39]]
  Favorite Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 39]]
  Service Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "services" WHERE "services"."id" = ?  [["id", 39]]
  Review Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 40]]
  Image Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 40]]
  Favorite Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."service_id" = ?  [["service_id", 40]]
  Service Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "services" WHERE "services"."id" = ?  [["id", 40]]
  Review Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
  Review Destroy (1.2ms)  DELETE FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."id" = ?  [["id", 5]]
  TRANSACTION (12.2ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
irb(main):003:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_check")
   (2.4ms)  PRAGMA foreign_key_check
=> [{"table"=>"participants", "rowid"=>13, "parent"=>"users", "fkid"=>1}]
irb(main):004:0> exit
```

Comment: Is there any logic behind your `Participant` class? To me this class looks like you're just using it to implement a many to many association, for which you could also use the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association class

Comment: I'm not sure if there actually is any meaning behind using `dependent` on a `through` association. My gut feeling would say that this is were your problem comes from

Comment: Do you have more information about the error? Is it showing which foreign key is triggering the error? I tried reproducing the error in my local environment but I could destroy a user with messages, participants and rooms. `dependent: :destroy` seems to do the job without problem.

Comment: @tonystrawberry I've added the error message I got. It's on the new post maybe take a look you'll see something.

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau mind you I was using a tutorial for this and they didn't explain his reasoning but when you check the code there are parts where it checks if the user is a participant in a room/conversation and is used in another place. Maybe check and you'll see something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a few notes:

```rb
has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy
has_many :rooms, through: :participants, dependent: :destroy
# this `dependent: :destroy` is redundant ^

# so is this one    v
has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
# because you have sqlite deleting it  v
add_foreign_key "messages", "users", on_delete: :cascade

# messages should probably belong to Participant in this set up
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :participant
end
```

The code that you show works, I assume you're not showing everything. This is the only way I know how to debug this:

```rb
User.last.destroy
#=> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (SQLite3::ConstraintException) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

# disable foreign key constraints
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF")

# this should work now (you have to run this again)
User.last.destroy

# check foreign keys manually to get a helpful error
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_check")
#=> [{"table"=>"payments", "rowid"=>1, "parent"=>"users", "fkid"=>0}]
# now you know where ^

# turn it back on
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
```

Comment: How thanks let me update. Fair warning it's very spaghetti code right now but hopefully makes sense. And again I'm just following what I saw and saw that it wasn't working when trying to delete it with active admin

Comment: After running `("PRAGMA foreign_key_check")` This is what I got. But I assume it's meant to produce an output?

irb(main):015:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_check")
   (1.9ms)  PRAGMA foreign_key_check
=> []

Comment: @WellingtonMitole almost. you have to run `User.last.destroy` after disabling the foreign keys, that lets you actually destroy the records and leave the offending foreign key constraint broken, so that when you run `PRAGMA foreign_key_check` it will show you something useful, so you can fix it.

Comment: Right right right i see. This is what i got
Also updating so you see the whole thing

irb(main):019:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_check")
   (6.9ms)  PRAGMA foreign_key_check
=> [{"table"=>"participants", "rowid"=>13, "parent"=>"users", "fkid"=>1}]

Comment: @WellingtonMitole that's something. i don't see in the logs that `participants` records are being loaded and destroyed, so the error makes sense. you have to reload your console for changes in your models to be picked up. this bit should be destroying the participants: `has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: added`belongs_to :participant` to Message model and restarted the console. Tried User.last.destroy and got `false`

Comment: Hey, actually it seems to be working! User was deleted! I want to poke around a bit first make sure everything else is okay but as far as I can see the problem has been solves so thank you so very much! Once I'm sure i'll run back and mark this as answered

Comment: Back again. Looks like it's still not working. You know how you said I had to reload the console for the changes to be picked up. I think in my frustration I may have changed this further before restarting it or something. Because it deleted one user but then trying it again isn't working. I've added the current state of the models and the error message. What do you think.

Comment: @WellingtonMitole don't add `dependent: :destroy` to `belongs_to` and `has_many` at the same time. you almost never need it on `belongs_to` anyway. use `destroy!` method in the console, because it is returning `false` which means it didn't work and there are probably validation errors.

Comment: you might want to reset you database or at least remove that particular participant record manually  since you have no user for it anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to handle it so that next time I delete a user the participant (when it has no user) is removed to?

Comment: @WellingtonMitole you can't have participants without users because `belongs_to :user` is required by default. and `has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy` should take care of destroying participants when user is destroyed. you should be ok from now on. because we've been messing with the database a little bit to figure things out, that particular record can be deleted manually.